# HTML/CSS min-width issue

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing an issue when setting a minimum width for an area. The problem is when the browser goes smaller than the min width, the background color/image set by CSS doesn't expand further than the window size. In other words if they were to scroll to the right to view all the content, the background seemingly disappears.

If the browser was 1000px wide, and my min-width is 1200px, then the 200px outside the min width area won't have the background.

Ideas?

DEMO: http://www.nickersonweb.com/demo/PMS/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. I had this problem once as well when I was making a site that had repeating horizontal edges. The solution is to also give your parent divs `<div class="banner">,<div class="body">,<div class="footer">` the css style of `min-width: 1000px;`. Now it will show just fine when you scroll.